# AWS IAM / QuickSight - User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxx:assumed-role/yyyy/nnnnnn is not authorized to perform: quicksight:RegisterUser on resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-iam, amazon-quicksight

I am trying to create QuickSight Users with identity type IAM using Terraform.

When applying the configuration I get the following error message:

> Error: Error registering QuickSight user: AccessDeniedException: 
>   arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxx:assumed-role/yyyy/nnnnnn is not authorized to
>   perform: quicksight:RegisterUser on resource arn:aws:quicksight:eu-west-1:xxxxx:user/default/user_to_create

I have AdministratorAccess attached to the role.

What should I do  ?

Comment: Are you sure that that assumed role definitely has administrator access policy? And you don't have any other restrictions such as through AWS Organizations or restrictions on that role?

Comment: yes, it is a crossaccount role with Full Admin access

Comment: The `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess` policy is literally * on * so it will work with anything. The only possibilities I can think of here are if you have a conflicting deny, a condition on usage or you are restricting at the account/organisation level via AWS Organizations. Could you edit you question to include a [mcve] of this error so others can attempt to reproduce your error in case there is some other reason this might happen?

Comment: When using identity_type QUICKSIGHT, this works with no problems, so here , I think the IAM parameters and account id are not correct , when using crossacount role ..

Comment: Any chance you can try to create an [mcve] so I can test this and see this behaviour? I have multiple AWS accounts as well so can test cross role assumption.

Comment: with aws cli, the user creation works fine, could this be due to Terraform version ?
I am using Terraform v0.12.21+ provider.aws v2.54.0

Comment: @MohamedAmineKharrez did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the IAM user, you need add the ARN of the IAM user.

```
resource "aws_quicksight_user" "IAM_user_invite" {
   iam_arn       = "arn:aws:iam::00000000000000:user/username"
   email         = "example@mail.com"
   identity_type = "IAM"
   user_role     = "ADMIN"
}
```